# How to use $hash to encrypt password

Tags: php, hash, password-hash

How do I make this $hash the password the user enters when they sign up to the website?  I've already got the log in working with $hash which works fine when I tested it with a manually inputted $hash password but can't get this form to create the encrypted passwords.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['emailaddress'],$_POST['password'],$_POST['name'])){
    $result= $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO user (emailaddress, password, name )
                        VALUES(:emailaddress, :password, :name)');
    $hash = password_hash(password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    unset($_POST['submit']);
    $result->execute($_POST);
    header("Location:admin.php");
}
```

Comment: You are only passing `$_POST` and never `$hash`. Something like `execute(array(':emailaddress' => $_POST['emailaddress'], ':password' => $hash, ...))` should work

Comment: password_hash(password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT); -> password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

Comment: [This is not encryption](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `$hash` into the `$_POST` before you execute the query

```
$_POST['password'] = $hash;
$result->execute($_POST);
```

Even better is what `kingkero` commented, that way you avoid unwanted values in the `$_POST`